# Symfony2 functional tests + Doctrine fixtures: Changes to entity won't save after flushing in doctrine fixtures

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, functional-testing, fixtures

I've encountered a problem while executing fixtures for my functional tests in Symfony 2.6. In the fixture I have a function for creating a base entity and flushing it to the database. Then I call this function from other functions that change the newly-created entity to something more elaborate (like setting relationships with other entities) and then I flush again.

However, when I check the database, the second flush makes no changes to the entity.

I've tried debugging and what I see is that UnitOfWork contains nothing scheduled for insertion/update before the second flush, although I execute functions set....().

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is the excerpt from my fixture:

```
class LoadTestApplications extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    const APPLICATION_ID_NOT_SUBMITTED_VALID = 37;

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        //other lines ommitted

        $this->loadNotSubmittedValidApplication($manager);

        //other lines ommited
    }

    private function loadNotSubmittedValidApplication(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $application = $this->createAndGetFilledApplication($manager, self::APPLICATION_ID_NOT_SUBMITTED_VALID,
            'property-property-empty', 'GROUP_INSTALLER', 'application-application-not-submitted-valid',
            'person-default', 'person-default', 'person-default', 'person-default');

        /** @var Installer $installer */
        $installer = $this->getReference('installer-installer1');

        /** @var InstallerContractor $installerContractor */
        $installerContractor = $this->getReference('installer-installer-contractor1');

        $application->setInstaller($installer);
        $installer->addApplication($application);

        $application->setInstallerContractor($installerContractor);
        $installerContractor->addApplication($application);

        $manager->persist($installer);
        $manager->persist($installerContractor);
        $manager->persist($application);
        $manager->flush(); // this saves no changes
    }

    private function createAndGetFilledApplication(ObjectManager $manager, $applicationId, $propertyReference,
       $acg, $referenceName, $contactReference, $improverReference, $billPayerReference, $propertyOwnerReference)
    {
        $application = new Application();
        $application->setId($applicationId);

        // lots of other set...() functions


        // that's for forcing our own ID on the entity, so we can force only
        // some of the entities to be loaded in the fixture and the id of
        // the entity stays the same no matter how many other entities have
        // been loaded before. This is crucial in our functional tests, so
        // we can go to e.g. http://..../application/15/show
        /** @var ClassMetadata $metadata */
        $metadata = $manager->getClassMetadata(get_class($application));
        $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);

        $manager->flush(); //this saves all changes from this function

        $this->addReference($referenceName, $application);

        return $application;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: This helps you managing fixtures for tests: https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle Are your sure you are executing them in the right order? Also, if the entity is not newly created, there is no need for calling $manager->persist(); Flush is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this time it was me being stupid.

We've recently changed the Application - InstallerContractor relationship to many-to-many (from one-to-many which we've had previously), so instead of using

```
setInstallerContractor()
```

I had to use

```
addInstallerContractor()
```

Thank's DerStoffel for your help, we will definitely try https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle!